# How to debug Core Data crash on fetch request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, memory-management, core-data

the second time I execute

```
[[MOC executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
```

after having said

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Login" inManagedObjectContext:MOC]];
NSError *error = nil;
```

it crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Included is the debug window, and it looks like the crash happens deep down in the Core Data stack. Any idea on how I should go about debugging this to find out what's going on?

[image]

(just in case, here's the link to the picture http://tinypic.com/r/zmavph/6  Click on the picture in the link and the debug window will get larger)

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is a memory error. You are using an object after deallocating it. It would be difficult to debug this without (more) code.

Have you tried running the analyzer (Xcode > Build > Build and Analyze)?

You may also want to break out the fetch and array lookup:

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [MOC executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]
if (!fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Error fetching Login: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    abort();
}

NSManagedObject *loginObject = [fetchedObjects lastObject];
```

Comment: As gerry3 suggested this is not a Core Data issue but a simple over-release of an object. Try turning on NSZombie and tracking down the over-released object.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a very useful [page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html) on CoreData debugging.

Comment: Above link is broken, try this instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/TroubleshootingCoreData.html